# jQuery validation inside a jQuery UI Dialog does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to use jQuery Validation plugin to validate the firstname and lastname textbox inputs inside a jQuery UI dialog. Every time the JS hits $("#formEditName").valid(); it just bombs. What am I missing?

My HTML:

```
<div id="dialogName" title="Edit Name:">
<form class="formEditName" id="formEditName" method="get" action="">
    <p class="validateTips">
        All form fields are required.</p>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="firstName">
            First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" />
        <label for="lastName">
            Last Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="" />
        <label for="suffix">
            Suffix</label>
             <input type="text" name="suffix" id="suffix" value="" />
             <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('#formEditName').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: "required"
    },
    {
    lastName: "required"
    }
});

$("#dialogName").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
    },
            open: $(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("#formEditName")),
    buttons: {
        "Update": function () {

                  if ($("#formEditName").valid()) {
                      alert("valid!");
                  } else {
                      alert("not valid");
                  }

    },
    Cancel: function () {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: It looks as though you have an extra "}" right after the Cancel function close bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#formEditName').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: "required",
        lastName: "required"
    }
});
```